# Safari: "Fetch API cannot load <url> due to access control checks." on same-origin request

Tags: safari, webkit, fetch-api

I'm calling `fetch()` in my web application and in Safari, the fetch Promise is being rejected and I'm seeing an error like this in the Web Inspector console:

```
Fetch API cannot load https://example.com/whatever due to access control checks.
```

This sounds like a CORS error, but I'm making a same-origin request (and there aren't any ad blockers involved or anything). What are other reasons this error might be happening?

Answer (score 13):

Despite the words "due to access control checks" in the logged console message, this isn't always related to access control at all.

In the WebKit source code, [any network request that fails synchronously is assumed to be an access control error](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/a57b46bd3293752a173273d8d39b06b6540977da/Source/WebCore/loader/cache/CachedResourceLoader.cpp#L1196-L1198)!

I ran into this and (with some patient use of lldb on a local debug build of WebKit) figured out that in my case, the fetch [was being immediately canceled](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/a57b46bd3293752a173273d8d39b06b6540977da/Source/WebCore/loader/cache/CachedResource.cpp#L196-L204) because there was a pending navigation on the page that initiated it; it was already in the process of unloading. In Safari, it seems this will prevent any new requests from that page from being started, and they're logged with this "access control" error.

Comment: Huge thanks for this Q&A, this helped us track down a nasty bug that was caused by a pending navigation canceling our requests. We'd probably still be looking for a root cause without this answer.